# "underlaid" or "underlain" in this context? What’s the correct form?

Tags: verbs, usage

I’m an advanced learner of english but… I can’t wrap my head around this. I need validation…

I came across this sentence, and got confused.

***The entire discussion is underlaid by the show's  trademark  dazzling  visual effects, which bring it to life.***

In my opinion, there is a mistake. What’s your take on it? Shouldn’t it be “underlain” the right fit here?

Looking forward to hearing from you,

Greetings from France,

P.S.: My entire dilemma lies with the verb which should used… to underlay or to underlie … If the latter is correct, then there’s a mistake in the above sentence. Am I mistaken?

*To put it in a nutshell…* I want to know which sentence makes sense:

1 - ***The entire discussion is underlaid by the show's  trademark  dazzling  visual effects, which bring it to life.***

OR

2 - ***The entire discussion is underlain by the show's  trademark  dazzling  visual effects, which bring it to life.***

Comment: Are you confused about the meanings of the two words? What does the dictionary say?

Comment: I just edited my post to clarify my demand,

Answer (score 1):

[According to the New World College Dictionary](https://www.grammarunderground.com/whats-the-past-tense-of-underlie.html), **underlay** is the past tense of **underlie**.

The past participle is **underlain**.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Let's put this into the active voice:

> The visual effects underlie the discussion.

The correct word is underlie "to be the root cause of a situation".

And "underlain" is standard past participle, so the passive voice should be "...is underlain (by...)"

"underlaid" is the past particle of "underlay" which means "to place something under or beneath.

The confusion is common in native speakers (almost to the point that the error is being accepted), and is further confused by the relationship to lie and lay.  Note that "underlie" is transitive, but "lie" isn't.

Comment: Hey James,
… thank you so much. I understand the confusion among native speakers but as a non-native speaker, I really need to get it right. I thank you again for your time and support,